# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Double C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a Datalist that is populated by a table and when I try to update the table from the Datalist I get the Exception: "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Double"

here is the click of the update button:

```
for (int x = 0; x < dlQtyBreak.Items.Count; x++)
{
    DataListItem item = dlQtyBreak.Items[x];

    string linenum = ((Label)item.FindControl("lblPBLinenum")).Text;
    string lowqty = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtPBLowQty")).Text;
    string highqty = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtPBHighQty")).Text;
    string price = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtPBPrice")).Text;
    string salesprice = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtPBSalesPrice")).Text;
    DAL.Util.updatePriceBreakRow(IQPDID(), lowqty, highqty, price, salesprice, linenum);

}
```

and this next code is the sql and the parameters

```
public static void updatePriceBreakRow(string IQPDID, string low, string high, string price, string sPrice, string linenum)
{
    string sql = "UPDATE ItemQtyPriceDiscTable SET  LowQuantity=@LowQty, HighQuantity=@HighQty, Price=@Price WHERE linenum=@lineNum";

    AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameterCollection parameters = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameterCollection();
    AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter param = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter();

    param.ParamName = "@IQPDID";
    param.ParamValue = IQPDID;
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Int;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@LowQty";
    param.ParamValue = low;
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@HighQty";
    param.ParamValue = high;
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@Price";
    param.ParamValue = price;
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@SalePrice";
    param.ParamValue = sPrice;
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@linenum";
    param.ParamValue = linenum;
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Int;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@update";
    param.ParamValue = lastUpdate;
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    parameters.Add(param);

    AdoUtil.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, parameters);
}
```

What can be causing this? When I do the same process on another datalist it works, only difference is that table uses all Int and varchar values where this one uses Float and varchar. If anyone has any helpful insight to help solve this problem it will be greatly appreciated. And if there is any other code that could be useful just ask and I can post it.

Thank you.

Comment: What value is contained in the string? The error message suggests that the value is an invalid value (e.g. an empty string)

Comment: I will try to use Convert.ToDouble() in all that string params. Supposing that something is not convertible to double. Perhaps you have a globalization problem

Comment: Are you doing any validation to make sure that the texts entered are actually of a numeric format that can be converted to a double?

Comment: The SalesPrice isn't always a populated field and currently has not been in any of the tests, is that what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say all your tests have been with out a value populated for "SalesPrice" try removing or commenting out

```
param.ParamName = "@SalePrice";
param.ParamValue = sPrice;
param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
parameters.Add(param);
```

and then run it as you have been and see if that results in the same or not. It could be holding up on that empty string.

and if it does turn out to be whats causing it just add a check in there and then exclude that parameter

Comment: I did what you suggested and put in a check to see that if the value is null to exclude the saleprice parameter. And that works great. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your other code works because they are using varchar datatpe and string is basically converted to varchar. However, in this situation you need to cast or convert these datatype to double. Because string can't be converted implicitly to double. Here is the solution;

```
param.ParamName = "@LowQty";
param.ParamValue = Convert.ToDouble(low);
param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
parameters.Add(param);
```

You need to do this for all other double parameters.

Comment: I have attempted this and results with the same exception. Thank you for your help in trying to solve this

Comment: have you tried with debugging in visual studio. I mean this will difnitly give you the line that is causing the error

Comment: I have debugged and the only thing it says is that a parameter value could not be converted from string to double. Doesn't specify which line

Comment: like this try { } catch(Exception e) { Response.Write(e.Message) }

Comment: after doing this I found that it was as pointed out saleprice being an empty value being passed so I did what was suggested and put a check to see if the value is null or empty and I now have it working. Thanks for your advice and help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a quick solvable error - try these things and comment what you have fond.

- Try replacing the reading from the controls in the float correlate SQL values to the default 5f - see if its a cast issue. If so, call the necessary cast method.
- Try to comment the real part of the code and use default values just for testing the mechanism itself.
- After you learn about the mechanism, try comment out parts of the code till you will find the correct location.
- Finally, add logs to the code to learn about the error's specific location

Comment on my answer what you found for specific help

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void updatePriceBreakRow(string IQPDID, string low, string high, string price, string sPrice, string linenum)
{
    string sql = "UPDATE ItemQtyPriceDiscTable SET  LowQuantity=@LowQty, HighQuantity=@HighQty, Price=@Price WHERE linenum=@lineNum";

    AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameterCollection parameters = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameterCollection();
    AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter param = new AdoUtil.ACESSQLParameter();

    param.ParamName = "@IQPDID";
    param.ParamValue =Convert.ToInt32(IQPDID);
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Int;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@LowQty";
    param.ParamValue =(float)Convert.ToDouble(low);
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@HighQty";
    param.ParamValue =(float)Convert.ToDouble(high);
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@Price";
    param.ParamValue = (float)Convert.ToDouble(price);
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@SalePrice";
    param.ParamValue =(float)Convert.ToDouble(sPrice);
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Float;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@linenum";
    param.ParamValue =Convert.ToInt32(linenum);
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.Int;
    parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParamName = "@update";
    param.ParamValue = lastUpdate;
    param.ParamDBType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    parameters.Add(param);

    AdoUtil.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, parameters);
}
```